# Error 404 in Powershell for Github script

Tags: git, powershell, github, github-api

I am currently trying to run the PowerShell For Github module to generate lists or Github repos and their corresponding branches using a ForEach loop.

**For each loop used:**

```
Set-GitHubAuthentication
enter code here`#Access Token has generated from Github has been passed
#Get list of Repositories in Github Organization
$OrgName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your Organization  name'
$repo = Get-GitHubRepository -OrganizationName $OrgName
$repo | Format-Table -Property name, full_name, visibility, updated_at

#parsing on the name property for the iteration to get branches
$reponame = $repo.name

#ForEach loop to iterate each repo name and their corresponding branches
$OwnerName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your Owner  name'
foreach ($repo in $reponame) {

   Get-GitHubRepositoryBranch -OwnerName "$OwnerName" -RepositoryName "$reponame"
    }
```

**Error gotten:**

The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
404 | Not Found
Not Found | https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#list-branches
This typically happens when the current user isn't properly authenticated. You may need an Access Token with additional scopes checked.
RequestId: 1919:0417:1D6C667:39908D7:618D59FD
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellForGithub\0.16.0\GitHubCore.ps1:557 char:9
+throw $newLineOutput
+~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (The remote serv...9908D7:618D59FD:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
404 | Not Found
Not Found | https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#list-branches
This typically happens when the current user isn't properly authenticated. You may need an Access Token with additional scopes checked.
RequestId: 1919:0417:1D6C667:39908D7:618D59FD

Please any assistance will be appreciated as to how to resolve this block.